# $routeProvider error with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I started learning *AngularJS* today and I am stuck with the *"routing"* part.  I have created a controller and a view (see below) however when I try to run it on my local server I get the following error:

```js
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module AMail due to: 
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

If the `ngRoute` service is built into Angular, why would the error suggest it's unknown?

<sub>**controller.js**</sub>

```js
var aMailServices = angular.module('AMail', []);
// Set up our mappings between URLs, templates, and controllers
    function emailRouteConfig($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
           controller: ListController,
           templateUrl: 'list.html'
        }).
        when('/view/:id', {
           controller: DetailController,
           templateUrl: 'detail.html'
        }).
        otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/'
       });
   }

// Set up our route so the AMail service can find it
aMailServices.config(emailRouteConfig);

messages = [{
       id: 0, 
           sender: 'jean@somecompany.com', 
           subject: 'Hi there, old friend',
       date: 'Dec 7, 2013 12:32:00', 
           recipients: ['greg@somecompany.com'],
           message: 'Hey'
       }];

// Publish our messages for the list template
function ListController($scope) {
    $scope.messages = messages;
}

// Get the message id from the route (parsed from the URL) and use it to
// find the right message object.
function DetailController($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.message = messages[$routeParams.id];
}
```

<sub>**index.html**</sub>

```html
<html ng-app="AMail">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A-Mail</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare the dependency on ngRoute:

```
var aMailServices = angular.module('AMail', ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: Also requires the `angular-route.js` to be included on the page

Comment: But that it not in the book. I am learning from O'Rileys AngularJS. Ok thanks for that. I thought route was built in directive with the standard Angular shipped code.

Comment: @user3283104 it used to be part of the main library but they decided to decouple it somewhere between versions `1.0` and `1.2` - you may find this link useful if you're working from an older book: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration